# When installing a custom ROM, why reboot before installing other modifications?

Tags: rom-flashing

Most ROM install instructions look like...

1. Boot into recovery
2. Wipe Data
3. Flash ROM
4. *Reboot*
5. *Boot into recovery*
6. Flash any Mods
7. Reboot
8. Done

Mods are modifications to the ROM code.  For example, replacing the Power Off menu with one that includes the option to reboot instead of just shut down.

Why are steps 4 & 5 needed?  I'm having a hard time seeing the purpose. Each reboot the cache rebuilds.  Why not just do it once?

Comment: Because the "developer" doesn't have a clue about what's he doing and why so he makes you do idiotic things. That's why.

Comment: I always thought this had to do with the ROM being deodexed and that the apks are odexed on the first boot, but it's just an unconfirmed impression I have, that's why this is not an answer.

Comment: It definitely does something during that reboot. I think the developer knows exactly what he's doing. The first boot of a new rom always takes longer than subsequent boots. I'm not sure exactly what it's doing, but presumably it's something that is required to flash most mods.

Comment: Richard Borcsik, you seem to have the most knowledge on the matter.  Can you answer why this is such an idiotic thing?  Make it an answer instead of a comment would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: On the first boot after a wipe (factory-reset/dalvik-cache-wipe), the *Dalvik-Cache* is rebuilt (@onik has been very close: yeah, that's the `*.dex` files). So if any mod is going to manipulate those, they need to be there in the first place. I'm just confused that your steps do *not* include a wipe of the Dalvik Cache...

Comment: @Izzy, wiping data, step #2 in my post, will wipe dalvik cache.  "Wiping" is really just deleting files within folders and dalvik is inside the data folder **/data/dalvik-cache/**. Wiping data and wiping dalvik is, although widely popular, unneeded and redundant for a fresh ROM install. And, when "dirty flashing" clearing the Dalvik Cache still isn't necessary because Android does it itself when needed. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25859/why-do-i-need-to-wipe-dalvik-cache

Comment: Ooops... Agreed to the wipe being done. But for the second (is it necessary?), please read again the information you linked yourself: *For best results it would be wise to perform both Wipe Data and Wipe Cache to ensure integrity and no program errors within the app itself.*