# Best way to update to latest versions of custom ROMs?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, rom

What is the easiest and most time effective way to update to different builds of a custom ROM ? 
Say for example, having an Infuse, I follow the builds of Cyanaogenmod 10 and they release updates every week or so. What I usually do is to use Titanium back up pro to backup my apps, flash ROM and do a restore. (which of course takes a lot of time)

Is there a better way to do this that I'm not aware of ? Does updating to a latest version need to have the same steps as flashing a new ROM entirely ?

Comment: Custom ROMs have no common mechanism for updates, akin to Linux distros.

Answer (score 3):

If you upgrade your CM10 to a newer build of CM10 you can just flash it right over the existing one, and you are ready. There is no need to backup all of your apps.

The newest builds of CyanogenMod have an updating system build-in however so you don't have to do it all by yourself. It is under System Settings - About Phone. It still downloads the complete zip of the newer build but handles the updating by itself.

There is, however, a new method to update your CyanogenMod. [CyanDelta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyandelta) is an app that calculates the difference between your build and the newest build and will only download and update this difference.

Comment: Just updated using CyanDelta instead of the CM build-in updater. I have it set that it checks for updates weekly. It will only need to download a couple of MBs for an update instead of the full package. So if you're staying with the same ROM (CM9/CM10), this is the fastest way to update.

Comment: Why wipe the dalvik cache?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik See here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25859/why-do-i-need-to-wipe-dalvik-cache

Comment: I asked that question :) The conclusion there was that it isn't unnecessary because it happens automatically.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik Seemed I looked over the fact that you asked that question, sorry about that. And I read the answer wrong. Clearing the dalvik cache is, indeed, not necessary. Edited that out of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do with my test devices is have [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager.license#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLmtvdXNoaWtkdXR0YS5yb21tYW5hZ2VyLmxpY2Vuc2UiXQ..) installed, which comes with an option to check and upgrade your custom firmware. Just go in there and select "Check for ROM Updates" (you must be using the paid version).

The beauty about using ROM Manager is the fact that you can also install other custom ROMs on your phone straight from it, as it will find the latest versions of various well known ROMs and offer you to download straight from the device.

[image: clockwork mod screen]

Once it's downloaded the firmware (be it an update or a different version), you can simply chose install from zip, and it will boot up and allow you to install it.

Quite easy and safe to do, since it does all the work for you, and stops you from messing something up.